# Subversive not showing up in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, subversive

I am trying to install subversive for eclipse helios on windows 7. I am seeing it as installed in the installation details, but it is not showing up as a perspective and also in windows/preferences/team. Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed that issue by granting my user writing access to the eclipse installation directory (default in "Program Files" is read access).

Comment: I changed my eclipse directory to Users/user folder and it worked. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

@squig - +1 
changing the directory permissions (I placed it under c:\program files\eclipse in Windows 7) caused the subversive plugin to work, after spending endless hours on trying to figure out the issue. 
 
The lame part from Eclipse side (or Subversive side, dunno) is that no error message was shown, it appeared as if the software was installed properly. Shame.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. But in my case the problem could not be solved be granting write access to the eclipse programm directory.

The reason was that I tried to use two versions (Mars and Neon.2) of eclipse in parallel. When I tried to install both programms into one directory in "C:\Programm Files (x86)\Eclipse" it was not possible to install plugins etc. to the newer version. Therefore I uninstalled the newer version and reinstalled it under "C:\Programm Files (x86)\Eclipse-Neon".

After this everything is fine. Even without write permissions to the programm directory.